# Spring scheduler: start at 12:25PM and run every 15 minutes after that

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler

I have 2 server, and on both scheduler runs:
1) Main server
2) Disaster recovery server

I want Fist scheduler to run at 12:15 and after 12:15 it should run every 15 minutes.
and second scheduler to start running at 12:25 and after that every 15 minutes it should run.

so both will not collide with each other.

Comment: This is probably a very complex system. Your simple description does not allow us to help your. Show us your code etc.

Comment: Hi @JHBonarius,

I have 2 server,
1) live server
2) Disaster recovery server

on both the server my scheduler runs, my scheduler just picks records from the database,  send sms to the user and then updates same record with flag = SENT


**PROBLEM** is that sometimes both servers scheduler collides and they pick same records and send 2 sms to the user.

Comment: Hi @JHBonarius, please let me know, if some more clarification is required, so you can suggest some good solution for me to come out of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot encode **start at 12:25pm and then every 15 minutes** using `@Scheduled(initialDelay = X, fixedDelay = Y, fixedRate = 15 * 60 * 1000)` nor using **CRON** expressions.

Fortunately you just need to encode **every 15 minutes starting at 25 (or 15) minutes past the hour, every hour, every day, every year**

Using an online cron expression generator we have (please note discussion around 5, 6 or 7 fields cron expressions below):

`@Scheduled(cron="0 25/15 * ? * *")` for every 15 min starting at 25 min past the hour and 
`@Scheduled(cron="0 15/15 * ? * *")` for every 15 min starting at 15 min past the hour.

Please don't forget `@EnableScheduling` annotation on your config.

#### *cron expressions discussion*

*Please note that cron expressions can have 5 (no seconds) as per `crontab` which Spring says it supports, however it fails with 5, 6 (seconds, and days of the month) which is the only option supported as far as my crude tests went, or 7 fields(seconds, days of month and days of week). Spring has rejected originally pasted 7 fields expression; I have tested with 6 and it worked correctly (but days and years were stars, i.e. ALL*

Comment: Hi @Diginoise

Thank a lot for the confirmation.
Below mentioned is my actual problem.
 
I have 2 server, 1) live server 2) Disaster recovery server on both the server my scheduler runs, my scheduler just picks records from the database, send sms to the user and then updates same record with flag = SENT 

**PROBLEM** is that sometimes both servers scheduler collides and they pick same records and send 2 sms to the user.

I am bit confuse, how can we solve this problem, without using any extra yml configuration param.


your help is hightly appericiated.

Comment: the cron expression you commented looks to be an invalid cron expression in spring boot as it spring cron takes 6 param only as per my understanding.

In quartz scheduling, this will work.
please correct me if my understanding is not correct.
apart from this, my actual problem for which I posted this question is different. that I have posted in above comment, please suggest

Comment: @SahilVerma - I have updated the answer about cron expressions. As long as system time on both servers is set correctly, and the time drifting (NTP daemon has to run on both servers) is addressed, using one schedule on production server, and another (shifted by 10 min) on DR server should be fine **UNLESS** it takes longer than 10min to process the sending of sms messages. Is your routine just asking for all records without SENT flag, and then iterating through these sending messages, and updating the records after each sent message?

Comment: I don’t have any idea about NTP daemon. Yah my scheduler just picks records without sent flag, then process and update the sent flag after processing. But sometimes both scheduler on different server picks same record and then send sms, because of which duplicassy is happening. Time on both the server is same. Each scheduler hardly takes 2 minutes to finish processing. Can you please assist. I appericiate your help in previous comment, if possible can you please elaborate more as this thing i bit new to me. Thanx in advance.

Comment: your comment looks bit promising, if i set cron to 0 25/15 * ? * * means it will run @ 12:25,12:40,12:55 and then 1:25,1:40,1:55 .... correct me if i missed something.